# i have afloat32 array how to create an Azure AudioInputStream

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

i have taken realtime audio data and used as float32 array how to convert it to azure AudioStreamInput

```
import numpy as np
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

class NumpyAudioStream(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, audio_array):
        self.audio_array = audio_array
        self.position = 0

    def read(self, buffer, offset, count):
        remaining = len(self.audio_array) - self.position
        to_read = min(remaining, count)
        buffer[:to_read] = self.audio_array[self.position:self.position+to_read]
        self.position += to_read
        return to_read
```

Tried this but  `'NumpyAudioStream' object has no attribute '_handle'` error occuring

i have afloat32 array how to create an Azure AudioInputStream

```
  @socketio.on('audio_data')
    def handle_audio_data(audioData):
    float32_array = struct.unpack('f' * (len(audioData) // 4), audioData)
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('AZURE_REGION'))
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStream(NumpyAudioStream(float32_array))
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
    recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    print(recognizer.recognize_once())
```

while doing this i got an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "\py312env\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\audio.py", line 213, in __read_callback File "\py312env\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\audio.py", line 213, in __read_callback ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "\py312env\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\speech\audio.py", line 213, in __read_callback TypeError: NumpyAudioStream.read() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'offset' and 'count' return obj.read(view) Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function PullAudioInputStream.__read_callback at 0x000001809EAB2F20> Traceback (most recent call last): ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

why the error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the provided information it seems, the data needs formatting to be used as input stream.

Below are changes/modification that can help to fix the issue.

1. In the `__init__` method, the float32 audio array is converted to int16 because the Azure Speech SDK expects audio data in int16 format.
2. The `read` method, the buffer size is divided by 2 to account for the fact that int16 values take up 2 bytes. This ensures that the correct number of samples is read from the audio array.
3. The audio data is written to the buffer using the `tobytes()` method, which converts the int16 audio array slice into a byte array. This is necessary because the buffer expects byte data.

Below is modified code for reference:

```py
class NumpyAudioStream(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, audio_array):
        super().__init__()
        self.audio_array = (audio_array * np.iinfo(np.int16).max).astype(np.int16)
        self.position = 0

    def read(self, buffer: memoryview) -> int:
        remaining = len(self.audio_array) - self.position
        to_read = min(remaining, buffer.nbytes // 2)
        buffer[:to_read * 2] = self.audio_array[self.position:self.position+to_read].tobytes()
        self.position += to_read
        return to_read * 2

    def close(self) -> None:
        pass
```

With the above changes, I was able to execute a float32 audio data file and get the results.
[image]